# How to deserialize using Newtonsoft in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to deserialize my JSON file in C# and getting error below:
  "An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in     Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code"

My JSON is:

```
    [{"Yes":"52","No":"41"}]
```

My c# code is

```
    public class survey
    {
        public string Yes { get; set; }
        public string No { get; set; }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("sample.json"))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<survey>(json);

           var a = items.Yes;
            TextBox1.Text = a;
        }
    }
```

Can any one please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Survey>>(jsonstr);
```

Instead of

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<survey>(json);
```

Because you are getting your JSON as an array of [Yes,No]

and then you will get the data like

```
var a = items[0].Yes;
```

**Edit**

The complete code might look like this

```
string jsonstr = File.ReadAllText("some.txt");
var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Survey>>(jsonstr);
var a = items[0].Yes;
```

The class looks like this

```
public class Survey
{
    [JsonProperty("Yes")]
    public string Yes { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("No")]
    public string No { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Screenshot for the output]

Comment: That's what I just started typing, but you were faster :)

Comment: @YalamanchiliHari, instead of copy pasting, try to understand the code and then use it. Also, read and comprehend the error message first. Its a matter of capitalization in the name.

Comment: Thanks for the help again :)

Comment: @YalamanchiliHari Another way of saying thanks on SO would be upvoting. Well you are welcome. :)